# how to call presentViewController with a delegate to self?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, presentviewcontroller

From current view controller, I am presenting a viewController as Model to get a large text input from user. I am able to do this but I don't know how to pass the entered text back to called view controller.

Can someone take at look and comment?

```
NotesController *vcNotes =  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FullNotes"];
[self presentViewController:vcNotes animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a delegate delegation protocol and add a `delegate` property to `NotesController`.

In the protocol, there should a method such as:

`- (void)notesController:(NotesController*)nc didFinishWithText:(NSString*)text;`

In your `NotesController`:

`@property (nonatomic, weak) id<NotesControllerDelegate> delegate;`

Now, before presenting, set the delegate to the presenting view controller:

```
NotesController *vcNotes =  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FullNotes"];
vcNotes.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:vcNotes animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now, in your notes controller, when you are ready, call the delegate method:

`[self.delegate notesController:self didFinishWithText:self.text];`